# Can't make a JSON (with Gson) out of a generic list

Tags: java, json, gson

i have made a generic list class:

```
public class FahrzeugListe<T extends Fahrzeug> implements TableModel {

private T[] array;
private int nextFreeSlot = 0;

private List<TableModelListener> tableListener = new ArrayList<TableModelListener>();

public FahrzeugListe(int capacity){
    array = (T[]) new Fahrzeug[capacity];
}

public void add (T o){
    if(nextFreeSlot == array.length){
        throw new IllegalStateException("Liste ist voll!");
    }
    array[nextFreeSlot] = o;
    nextFreeSlot++;
    for(TableModelListener l : tableListener){
        l.tableChanged(new TableModelEvent(this));  /
    }
}
```

Its ofc not the whole class, but i think, its the important part for my problem.
I have another class for making those "Fahrzeug"-objects, its e.g. a car or bus...
Those objects i add through a GUI into this list, and to my GUI i added a button, where i wanted to save this list to JSON, so, when i start my program again, i can take the information out of my list first and then work with it.
In my GUI class i implemented the following method for a button "Save":

```
private class SaveListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String json = new Gson().toJson(fahrzeugListe);
        System.out.println("The text, should be written in jason: " +json);
    }
}
```

Somehow i get this error message:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Anybody can help me please? :)

Comment: Stackoverflow error - you probably have an infinite recursion in the code somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
private transient List<TableModelListener> tableListener = new ArrayList<TableModelListener>();
```

I added the keyword transient, and everything works fine now xD